# How to use .nextAll() (or another method) to clear other radio inputs after current one

Tags: jquery

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockitdev/e755d/28/)

I want to be able to clear all radio buttons that are siblings of my parent div download. Example, If Choice 1 of Radio Button Choice 2 is selected, i want to clear out the values in Radio Button Choice 3 and Radio Button Choice 4.

```
$('input:radio[name=radio-choice-2]').change(
    function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'choice-1') {
            $(this).parent().nextAll('div :radio').removeAttr('checked');
        }   
    });
<form method="post" action="">
    <div id="question-1">
         <h4>Radio Button Choice 1</h4>

        <label for="radio-choice-1-a" class="checkbox inline">Choice 1
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1-a" tabindex="2" value="choice-1" />
        </label>
        <label for="radio-choice-1-b" class="checkbox inline">Choice 2
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1-b" tabindex="3" value="choice-2" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id="question-2" class="collapse-group">
         <h4>Radio Button Choice 2</h4>

        <label for="radio-choice-2-a">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-2-a" tabindex="2" value="choice-1" />
        <label for="radio-choice-2-b">Choice 2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-2-b" tabindex="3" value="choice-2" />
    </div>
    <div id="question-3" class="collapse-group">
         <h4>Radio Button Choice 3</h4>

        <label for="radio-choice-3-a">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-3" id="radio-choice-3-a" tabindex="2" value="choice-1" checked />
        <label for="radio-choice-3-b">Choice 2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-3" id="radio-choice-3-b" tabindex="3" value="choice-2" />
    </div>
    <div id="question-4" class="collapse-group">
         <h4>Radio Button Choice 4</h4>

        <label for="radio-choice-4-a">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-4" id="radio-choice-4-a" tabindex="2" value="choice-1" checked />
        <label for="radio-choice-4-b">Choice 2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-4" id="radio-choice-4-b" tabindex="3" value="choice-2" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input:radio').change(function () {
    $(this).parents('div').nextAll('div').each(function () {
        $(this).find(':input').prop('checked',false);
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/e755d/31/)**

Comment: I think you want `.prop('checked',false)` instead of `.removeAttr('checked')`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('input:radio').change(function () {   
   $(this).closest('div[id^="question"]').nextAll('div[id^="question"]').find(':radio').prop('checked', false)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tuUmn/)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that using traditional DOM traversal methods, you would need to go up the tree, further across, and then down — but how much further up and down isn't really intrinsic to the function. What you want is to look at the DOM as a linear sequence, and pick all the radio buttons that occur after the one in question — regardless of how they're nested.

I wrote a plugin for exactly this a while back: [jQuery sequential traversal](https://github.com/barneycarroll/jquery.sequentialTraversal.js).

Using this, the code to get the radios you're after is as follows:

```
$(this).sequentialNextAll(':radio').removeAttr('checked');
```

[I forked your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/MfqEw/) to show how little difference it presents to your original.