# Hide div after first two that do not contain checked radio buttons

Tags: jquery

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockitdev/e755d/57/)

After the first two mini-cog divs, if the radio button contained within it is not checked I want it to hide the div but it's just hiding all divs after the first 2 (the 5th is checked so it should not be hidden in this example).

**jQuery :**

```
$("div.mini-cog").slice(2).each(function () {

    // this is hiding Radio Button Question 5, but since its checked i want it to appear
    // $(this).find(':input').not(':checked').parent('div').hide();
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div id="question-1" class="mini-cog">
         <h4>Radio Button Question 1</h4>

        <label for="radio-choice-1-a" class="checkbox inline">Choice 1
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1-a" tabindex="2" value="choice-1" />
        </label>
        <label for="radio-choice-1-b" class="checkbox inline">Choice 2
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1-b" tabindex="3" value="choice-2" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id="question-2" class="mini-cog">
         <h4>Radio Button Question 2</h4>

        <label for="radio-choice-2-a">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-2-a" tabindex="2" value="choice-1" />
        <label for="radio-choice-2-b">Choice 2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-2-b" tabindex="3" value="choice-2" />
    </div>
    <div id="question-3" class="mini-cog">
         <h4>Radio Button Question 3</h4>

        <label for="radio-choice-3-a">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-3" id="radio-choice-3-a" tabindex="2" value="choice-1" />
        <label for="radio-choice-3-b">Choice 2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-3" id="radio-choice-3-b" tabindex="3" value="choice-2" />
    </div>
    <div id="question-4" class="mini-cog">
         <h4>Radio Button Question 4</h4>

        <label for="radio-choice-4-a">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-4" id="radio-choice-4-a" tabindex="2" value="choice-1" />
        <label for="radio-choice-4-b">Choice 2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-4" id="radio-choice-4-b" tabindex="3" value="choice-2" />
    </div>
    <div id="question-5" class="mini-cog">
         <h4>Radio Button Question 5</h4>

        <label for="radio-choice-5-a">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-5" id="radio-choice-5-a" tabindex="2" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
        <label for="radio-choice-5-b">Choice 2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-5" id="radio-choice-5-b" tabindex="3" value="choice-2" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please address your previous question with this same code as others have already donated time to help you with it, too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240346/how-to-use-nextall-or-another-method-to-clear-other-radio-inputs-after-curr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/e755d/61/

JS:-

```
$("div.mini-cog").slice(2).each(function () {
    if($(this).find(':input').not(':checked').length!=1)
        $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
if ($(this).find(':input:checked').val() === undefined) $(this).hide();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/e755d/58/)**

Comment: By way of explanation, since you have an unchecked radio button in Question 5, it will match and cause the div to be hidden. What you need is a selector that checks for the absence of a checked button, rather than the presence of an unchecked one.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
$("div.mini-cog:gt(1)").filter(function () {
    if($(this).find('input:not(:checked)').length > 1)
        return this;
}).hide();
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/e755d/63/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/e755d/59/

If so you can jut use:

```
document.querySelector('input[checked]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange, no one use `filter()`?  **EDIT**  i didn't saw Dom's answer, all my apologies

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e755d/65/)

```
$("div.mini-cog").slice(2).each(function () {
    $(this).filter(function () {
        return !$('input:checked', this).length
    }).hide();
});
```